How to get Multi Selection direction it started from?
When developing using range in JavaScript, if you press the arrow key through keydown
How to get multi-selection direction it started from? (shift + > | shift + <)
Take the string "ABC" as an example

Place the cursor between A and B, Press shift + > twice
-> startOffset 2, endOffset 3 -> startOffset 1, endOffset 3
Place the cursor after C, Press shift + < three times And Press shift + > once
-> startOffset 0 endOffset3 -> startOffset 1, endOffset 3

Both have the same offset,

endOffset has been changed and 2)startOffset has been changed.

How to get multi-selection direction from arrow keydown event?
In case of multi-select, Customize the cursor when press the arrow key.
window.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
  let range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
  if(e.keyCode == 37) { // arrow left <
     if(~~~) {
       range.setStart(~~);
       range.setEnd(~~);
     }
  } else if(e.keyCode == 39) { // arrow right >
    if(~~~) {
       range.setStart(~~);
       range.setEnd(~~);
     }
  }
});


The cursor position will always be at either the start or the end of the selection - if selecting to the right (your example 1) then it's at the end / if selecting to the left (your example 2) then it's at the start.
So you can check where the cursor is and that will give you the "direction".
let cursorPos = window.getSelection().extentOffset;

